# PHP Multiplication not working

Tags: php, math

```
$databtcguild = file_get_contents('http://btcguild.com');
preg_match('~<b>Pool Speed</b></a> (.*?) TH/s~',$databtcguild,$btcguild);
$btcguildhashrategh = ($btcguild[1] * 1000);

echo $btcguildhashrategh;
echo "<br>";
echo $btcguild[1];
```

For some reason this code is outputting the wrong answer. For example, $btcguild[1] will equal 12,747 and this code will output 12000. I'm completely lost here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post an actual sample of the exact input `$databtcguild`.

Comment: If you are expecting `,` as a thousands separator, PHP may be misinterpreting it as a decimal separator. For example `echo intval('12,752');` prints `12`, hence your 12000 when multiplied by 1000

Comment: That’s only natural, because the literal `12,747` parsed into a number _is_ 12 – valid number characters `1` and `2`, followed by an _invalid_ one, the comma – so this is where PHP breaks off when parsing this into a numeric value. If you want it to mean `12.747`, then you have to replace the comma beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

The "hash speed" value you are extracting from that site has a value with a comma in it:

> 12,747

PHP needs to convert this string to a numeric value, and the comma causes the numeric value `12` to be returned (`,` is interpreted as a decimal)

Make sure you strip all non-numeric characters before multiplying:

```
//keep only values 0-9 and decimal (period)
$hash_speed = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $btcguild[1]);

$btcguildhashrategh = ($hash_speed * 1000); //returns 12747000
```

Answer (score -2):

Try explicitly type-casting the result: `$btcguildhashrategh = ((double)$btcguild[1] * 1000);`
Otherwise PHP will convert it into an `int`.

Comment: PHP will not convert it into an int. If one side is a float the result will be a float.

Comment: @PeeHaa Indeed you are right. I didn't recognize the `,` instead of `.`